# Obtener el valor del input que trae por defecto datatables

Tags: javascript, html5, datatables

quisiera obtener el valor del input de busqueda de datatables, el que esta en el recuadro color rojo
[image: DataTables]

en el inspector de elementos se puede acceder al input, mi idea es ponerle un id="", para posteriormente capturar su valor, el problema es que no encuentro donde colocarselo o si por lo menos es la mejor opción

Comment: Con un **id** es mucho mejor, por que dices que pueda no ser la mejor opción?

Comment: Si también creo que con el id es lo mejor, el problema que no se donde ponerlo, es decir en que parte encuentro el archivo donde esta el código del input, para ponerle el id

Comment: ahí si es compleja la cosa y por acá es complicado saberlo

Answer (score 4):

Puedes obtener el valor del input de la siguiente forma:

```
const table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.search();
```

A continuación, te dejo un ejemplo sobre como obtener el valor mientras se está buscando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $dt = $('#myTable').DataTable();
  
  $dt.on('search.dt', function(e) {
    $('#info').html('Texto buscado: ' + $dt.search());
  });
});
```

```css
#info {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="info"></div>

<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Row 1 Data 1</td><td>Row 1 Data 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2 Data 1</td><td>Row 2 Data 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: algo como asi?                                                            $(document).ready(function () {

   const table = $('#myTabla').DataTable();
   table.search().keypress(function () {

       alert(table);
        
 });

});

Comment: @JohnG La función `.search()` solo retorna valor, no entrega el elemento. Tratare mejorar mi respuesta para que cubra tu caso

Comment: Quedó actualizada la respuesta para incluir el ejemplo

Comment: Que buena información como sería lo inverso? mandarle un valor al input búsqueda?